# html shows the result before ng-if evaluates the regular expression in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<div class="alert alert-danger hidden-xs" role="alert" ng-if="OrderDetails.length == 0" style="font-size: large; font-stretch: expanded;
    font-weight: bold;">
  
  
<p>We're sorry,you currently have no last Order details, but items you've thought will be added automatically when you place an order.</p>
  
  
    </div>
```

Hi, as you can see from above before my result loads from controller the above html loads on my browser, is there any way I can prevent this div to load before my result loads and available to show on my web page?

Comment: yes , as it's an array

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for  [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

From the documentation:

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

```
<input id = "search"  ng-if="someCondition" ng-cloak>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-bind` [read more](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)

`<p ng-bind="contentToShow"></p>`

and in your controller

`$scope.contentToShow = "We're sorry,you currently have no last Order details, but items you've thought will be added automatically when you place an order.";`

Comment: Thank you for this, this is  helpful :)